# create new object of SharedPreference class and call function in android

Tags: android

i am using this code

```
public void addValue(Context context, String username){
                    List un = loadValue(context);
                    if (un == null)
                        un = new ArrayList();
                    un.add(username);
                    storeValue(context,un);
                }
                SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
```

how can i create a new object of Shared Preference class and call function addValue??

Comment: You can not store a function in your SharedPreferences. What you could do is to store a variable with a specific value which you evaluate and call the function e.g. in a switch-case or if-else block.

Comment: Elaborate your question. Its very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Why you want to call function addValue from Shared Preference object?

Answer (score 0):

I hope its helpful.

Stored data as Key-Value Pair

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("StoreData", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString("LastLatitude", strlat);
editor.putString("LastLongitude", strlng);
editor.putLong("ClockedInTime",currentLocalTime.getTime());
editor.commit();
```

Retrive Stored data

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("StoreData", MODE_PRIVATE);
String LastLatitude = prefs.getString("LastLatitude", "");
```